# ConvertFrom-Json : Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have an API and when I run the PowerShell script:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop'|ConvertFrom-Json
```

I get the error:

> ConvertFrom-Json : Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds the value set on the maxJsonLength property. Parameter name: input At line:2 char:72 + Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop'|ConvertFr ... + ~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

My understanding is the API is quite large but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.

I tried using:

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop'|ConvertFrom-Json 
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$jsonserial= New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = $somevalue 
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($rawtext) 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue
```

I still got the same error.

Comment: I edited and formatted the code. Please check if I removed or added some whitespace that is harmful.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of issues here.

```
Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop'|ConvertFrom-Json
```

You are still using the same method here. And then it seems like you have pasted some somewhat relevant code under it. What does `$rawtext` and `$somevalue` hold?

```
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = $somevalue 
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($rawtext) 
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue
```

There is no need to change `MaxJsonLength` twice, especially not after the deserialization.

You want to remove the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet because of the length limit and use the webrequest response for the JavaScriptSerializer.

```
$url = "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Web.Extensions")
$jsonserial = New-Object -TypeName System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
$jsonserial.MaxJsonLength = [int]::MaxValue
#Because of SSL requirements
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
#Getting webresponse/JSON data, stored in a varibale
$content = (Invoke-WebRequest $url).Content
#Deserializing the JSON data
$Obj = $jsonserial.DeserializeObject($content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Welp, if you follow the logic above, you are trying to convert the webrequest object from JSON which it is not.  If the body is what is in JSON then you need to do the following.

```
ConvertFrom-Json (Invoke-WebRequest 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/Place/Type/OysterTicketShop').Content
```

That is about it.